# Manual colour scale and factors in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi I am producing the following graph in ggplot:

```
p<-df_tra %>%
  filter(Theta_param ==1 & Gamma_param==0.76,Int_dis=='Bench', Rho_param %in% c(0, 1)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Debt, y = Gini_tra , colour =Rho_param)) +
  geom_line()+
  scale_color_hue(labels = unname(c('CD production', 'Linear Technology')))+
  #scale_color_manual("",values = rev(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(3,'Blues')))+
  xlab("Public Debt") +
  ylab("Wealth Inequality [Gini Index]") +
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(text =element_text(family="Times New Roman"),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.text.align = 0,
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 8),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 8),
        legend.position= c(0.2, 0.9))
print(p)
```

Which gives the following picture:

[image]

Now I want to change colours and I use the following code:

```
p<-df_tra %>%
  filter(Theta_param ==1 & Gamma_param==0.76,Int_dis=='Bench', Rho_param %in% c(0, 1)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Debt, y = Gini_tra , colour =Rho_param)) +
  geom_line()+
  scale_color_hue(labels = unname(c('CD production', 'Linear Technology')))+
  **scale_color_manual("",values = rev(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(3,'Blues')))+**
  xlab("Public Debt") +
  ylab("Wealth Inequality [Gini Index]") +
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(text =element_text(family="Times New Roman"),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.text.align = 0,
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 8),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 8),
        legend.position= c(0.2, 0.9))
print(p)
```

which produced the desired colours but, unfortunately the legends that I want to keep are gone and are replaced by the numeric equivalent of the factors I used to reproduce the graph.

[image]

What goes wrong and the second chunk of code eliminated my legends ? can someone help me to reproduce what is in the first picture, but with the colours of the second graph ?

I have attached using 'dput' the text file with my df to reproduce the figures.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/g6d13tiebcv0vze/df_diagram.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you ran the second code block, you will have seen this warning:

> Scale for 'colour' is already present. Adding another scale for 'colour', which will replace the existing scale.

which tells you that `scale_color_manual`, which has no labels, is overriding `scale_color_hue`.

So one solution is to remove the `scale_color_hue` and add the labels to `scale_color_manual`.

```
df_tra %>%
  filter(Theta_param ==1 & Gamma_param==0.76,Int_dis=='Bench', Rho_param %in% c(0, 1)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Debt, y = Gini_tra, colour = Rho_param)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_manual(labels = unname(c('CD production', 'Linear Technology')),
                     values = rev(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(3,'Blues'))) +
  xlab("Public Debt") +
  ylab("Wealth Inequality [Gini Index]") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(text = element_text(family = "Times New Roman"),
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.text.align = 0,
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 8),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 8),
        legend.position = c(0.2, 0.9))
```

[image]

Another solution would be to use `dplyr::mutate` and replace the 0/1 in the original data with the labels, so you don't need to add them manually.